# createQueryBuilder leftJoin using Doctrine DQL and Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

This code doesn't work. Can anybody help me? The code is:

```
class ResultRepository extends EntityRepository
{
     public function findAllByUserResultVote($id_vote)
     {
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
           ->leftJoin('r.user' , 'u')
           ->leftJoin('r.answer' , 'a')
           ->leftJoin('r.vote' , 'v')

           //Where idVote (Table result) == id (Table vote)
           ->where('r.idVote = :idVote')
           ->setParameter('idVote', $id_vote)
           ->getQuery();
        return $query->getResult();
     }
}
```

I have an entity User, Answer, Vote, Result.

And I have 4 tables:
**User:** *id* (primary), **name**, ...
**Vote:** *id* (primary), **question**, ...
**Answer:** *id* (primary), idVote, **answer** ...
**Result:** **id** (primary), *idUser* (id <-table user), *idVote* (id <-table vote), *idAnswer* (id <-table answer), ...

Result contains only the id but I need return for example:
**Instead of:** 1, 6, 5, 3
**This:** 1, u.name, v.question, a.answer

Comment: addSelect will help you out.  Take some time to read through the documentation: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html.  DQL is different than SQL and you will waste a lot of time until you understand the differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't have to write join conditions manually. It's ORM's responsibility to do this.
2. You should use `Vote` object rather than its ID in `where` clause.

   ```
   $vote = ...;

   $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
      ->leftJoin('r.user', 'u')
      ->leftJoin('r.answer', 'a')
      ->leftJoin('r.vote', 'v')
      ->where('r.vote = :vote')
      ->setParameter('vote', $vote)
      ->getQuery();
   ```

Comment: I've just tested and I'm go on getting error.Why I should use Vote object rather than its ID in where clause? r.idVote (table Result) is an id (maybe a lot of results). And $id_vote is only one, unique (table Vote).

Comment: What kind of error? You should use objects rather their properies as you're working on **object model**, not database model. Using objects will make your code more verbose, and easier to maintain.

Comment: I'd have to use Entity Relationships/Associations??

Comment: You should simply place entire object in place of association comparison (`r.vote = :vote`).